# Angular RXJS handle errors globally with interceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm kind of new in RXJS, and I've ran into a problem. I have several HTTP calls, and want to have a global http error interceptor. Basically, I'm trying to catch all the error responses, where the `Content-Type` is `"problem+json"`. Here's what I tried so far:

error.interceptor.ts

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      tap(f => f, errorResponse => {
        const {headers} = errorResponse;
        if (errorResponse instanceof HttpErrorResponse && headers.get('Content-Type').includes('application/problem+json')) {
          this.messageService.error(errorResponse.error.title, errorResponse.error.message);
        }
        return throwError(errorResponse);
      })
    );
  }
```

login.component.ts

```
  submitForm(): void {
    const loginRequest: LoginRequest = new LoginRequest(this.loginForm.value);

    this.http.request(Resource.AUTH, Request.POST, loginRequest)
      .subscribe((next) => {
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

My real problem is, that the messageService is called from the error interceptor as it should, the console.log gets executed in the error callback, but somehow the success callback is also executed, although the status code was 401.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I've just deleted the interceptor, and checked if both success and error callbacks are executed and the result is yes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the operator tap its just a logger so avoid to use that for logic purposes.

```
intercept(
        request: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            retry(1), // optional
            catchError((error) => {
                console.log("TCL: HttpErrorInterceptor -> constructor -> error", error)

                if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                 const {headers} = error;
                this.messageService.error(errorResponse.error.title, 
                 errorResponse.error.message);
                 }
                    return next.handle(request); // go with the flow
                } else {
                  return throwError(error);
               }
               return EMPTY;
            }),
        );
    }
```

You can add in the if this condition && headers.get('Content-Type').includes('application/problem+json'), but angular will handle all errors automatically (400codes - 500codes).